# datetime datetime to timetuple error - How to convert datetime datetime to timetuple?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am getting an error when I try to convert my datetime.datetime object to a timetuple. I have a method that compares times and returns a string description of the time (eg. afternoon, evening, etc.)

I've tried importing different modules. Right now I am using "from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time". I also have printed the type object I want to convert and it shows that it is a datetime.datetime object, but when I try to run .timetuple it says it is receiving an int.

tweetTime is the tweepy module response from tweet.created_at

```
    tweetTime = time.mktime(tweetTime.timetuple())
    if tweetTime <= datetime.time(03,00,00):
        return "early am"
    elif tweetTime <= datetime.time(05,00,00):
        return "am"
    elif tweetTime <= datetime.time(10,00,00):
        return "morning"
    elif tweetTime <= datetime.time(16,00,00):
        return "afternoon"
    elif tweetTime <= datetime.time(18,00,00):
        return "midday"
    else:
        return "evening"
```

Additional code using datetime

```
now=datetime.today().now()
prev=now-timedelta(minutes=1440)
```

This is the error im getting: " descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'"

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: Additional code has been added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about the function calls to time (i.e. `datetime.time(03,00,00)`).

you are already importing `time` from the module `datetime`, so you don't have to write `datetime.time`. Try making your code look like this....

```
if tweetTime <= time(3,00,00):
    return "early am"
elif tweetTime <= time(5,00,00):
    return "am"
elif tweetTime <= time(10,00,00):
    return "morning"
elif tweetTime <= time(16,00,00):
    return "afternoon"
elif tweetTime <= time(18,00,00):
    return "midday"
else:
    return "evening"
```

This should take care of the error you mentioned in your original question.